# Rails 7 Heroku Deployment Issue with Sprockets::DoubleLinkError after accidentally installing importmap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I just tried git push heroku my application after accidentally installing importmap. Already removed files in the build folder but nothing fixed.

```
Sprockets::DoubleLinkError: Multiple files with the same output path cannot be linked ("application.js")
remote:        In "/tmp/build_2d09f004/app/assets/config/manifest.js" these files were linked:
remote:          - /tmp/build_2d09f004/app/assets/builds/application.js
remote:          - /tmp/build_2d09f004/app/javascript/application.js
```

```
 Precompiling assets failed. remote:  ! remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app. remote:  remote:  !     Push failed remote:  ! remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: ab799e63874dc076706c77b558d3fd6e4102f755 remote:  ! remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version ab799e63874dc076706c77b558d3fd6e4102f755 remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch. remote:  ! remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run: remote:  ! remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main remote:  ! remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior: remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
```